# "Злачные места"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "злачные места"? Если от "злак", то почему употребляется в значении "уголовный", "бандитский", "противозаконный"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хороший вопрос!

Для начала, злачное - не от злак в современном значении, а от праславянского злoкъ - зелень. Это слово, родственное "зола", "золото"(!), означало обильные поля, всходы и переосмыслилось в "обильный, плодородный". Именно это значение было вложено в понятие "злачное место", известное по православной заупокойной молитве. В этом значении слово встречается еще у Пушкина. 
Такой изначально смысл был вложен и в понятие "злачного места" в переносном значении: место где обильно произрастает всякая всячина, не в последнюю очередь - грехи и пороки.
Стоит замеить, что т.н. "народная этимология" усиленно выводит значение от "зло", но эта версия не имеет ничего общего с истиной.

Да, забыл. Значение "уголовный" и подобные это уже перебор. Злачное место в современном значении - порочное, греховное. Но совсем не обязательно бандитское и даже вряд ли таковое.

Answer (score 0):

[злачное место | ru.wiktionary.org](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE) предлагает такой вариант:

буквально: место, где растут злаки — выражение из православной заупокойной молитвы («…в месте злачнем, в месте покойнем…»). Так в текстах на церковнославянском языке называется рай. Переносное значение этого выражения — «веселое место» или «сытное место» (таким местом в старой России мог быть кабак).

Answer (score 0):

В сакральных текстах слово *злачный* определённо — от *злака*. Из словаря Ц-СЯ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]